# Begin read from arbitary position in array

Tags: algorithm

I wonder if there's a way to begin reading from an arbitrary position in a array. E.g. if I have a array of size 10 and it begins reading from position 4. Then it should continue on reading from position `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3`

I was uncertain with tag, so if have picked wrong tag please do change it for me.

Comment: It depends on the type of list. With a linked list, it is not possible to start in the middle without a reference to an element. With most other types of lists it is possible. What programming language are you using? What have you tried so far? Post some code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Asaph: sorry, I didn't knew that linked list is traditionally called list. What I meant is an array. I change my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
offset = 4;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout << x[(i+offset)%n] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can index using the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which is written as `%` in most languages:

```
x = list[i % list.length]
```

This will give you the desired effect of wrapping around when you reach the end of the list instead of attempting to index out of bounds.

This assumes 0-based indexing. If you use 1-based indexing you have to add one to the result of the modulo operation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "list". Traditionally in computer science, "list" usually means "linked list". In this case, you have to traverse the list in order to get to a particular element.

If you need/want to be able to start reading from arbitrary positions efficiently, you probably want to avoid linked lists, but the exact alternatives you have (easily) available will vary with the programming language, libraries, etc., you're using.

Edit: for an array, it's generally trivial -- just specify the starting position directly, and take the remainder after dividing by the array size.

Comment: i meant an array, I'm going to the change it on my question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the list [*circular*](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) (like they do it in the Linux kernel).